# Apply method in Pandas showing wrong data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

While using apply() method on the StackOverflow dataset, I got an error. I was trying to find the length of each reply in the "HOBBYIST" column. The code I used was:

```
result = pd. read_csv ("survey_results_public.csv")
result ["HOBBYIST"]. apply (len)
```

The error I got was:
**TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()**

Even though the data in the "HOBBYIST" column included only "Yes" and "No" (and some Null values) which is clearly not float data type.

later I changed my code to:

```
result ["HOBBYIST"]. astype (str). apply (len)
```

This showed the correct result but why did apply method consider values like "Yes" and "No" to be float data type?

Comment: Maybe there are `NaN` values in the column?

Comment: There maybe Null data or Empty data in the specified column

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also remove all Null records to prevent such issues. Here is the sample

```
#import library
import pandas as pd

#sample data
result = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Ivan','John','Shaun'],'HOBBYIST':['Yes',None,'No']})
result
```

> Result Dataset with Null data

```
    name    HOBBYIST
0   Ivan    Yes
1   John    None
2   Shaun   No
```

Using dropna() method we can omit all Null records as follows

```
#removing or dropping all null records
result = result.dropna()
result
```

> Resulting Dataset without Null Records

```
    name    HOBBYIST
0   Ivan    Yes
2   Shaun   No
```

Now you can perform len on apply() function.

```
df["HOBBYIST"].apply(len)
```

> Result

```
0    3
Name: HOBBYIST, dtype: int64
```

**N.B**. Make sure that your specified column is string type. Unless it's better to convert the column to string type as above mentioned answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent `pandas.read_csv()` from inferring the data types for certain columns.

```
result = pd.read_csv("survey_results_public.csv", dtype={"HOBBYIST": str})
```